# Python/MySQL query error: `Unknown column`

Tags: python, mysql, command-line, mysql-connector

This script is meant to act as a command-line front-end to add records to a locally hosted MySQL database.

I am getting this error:

`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'watermelon' in 'field list'`

But **watermelon is the value I am trying to enter, not the column name!**

Here is the script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

#use command line as front end to enter new rows into locally hosted mysql database

import mysql.connector

#create inputs
new_fruit = raw_input('What fruit do you want to add? ')
new_fruit_type = raw_input('Which type of ' + new_fruit + '? ')

#connect to dbase
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='xxxx', database='play')

#instansiate cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()

#define sql statement
add_record = "INSERT INTO fruit (name, variety) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (new_fruit, new_fruit_type)

#execute sql
cursor.execute(add_record)

#close out
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

And the table schema:

```
mysql> describe fruit;
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | char(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| variety | char(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 13):

```
"INSERT INTO fruit (name, variety) VALUES (%s, %s)" % ("watermelon", "melon")
```

Literally becomes

```
INSERT INTO fruit (name, variety) VALUES (watermelon, melon)
```

Instead of strings, `watermelon` and `melon` are columns. To fix this, put quotes around your `%s`.

```
"INSERT INTO fruit (name, variety) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (new_fruit, new_fruit_type)
```

However, you should run it as:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fruit (name, variety) VALUES (%s, %s)", (new_fruit, new_fruit_type));
```

Notice we took away the quotations around the `%s` and are passing the variables as the second argument to the `execute` method. `Execute` prevents sql injection from the variables as well as wraps strings in quotation marks.

For more information, see http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples

Answer (score 3):

The issue is here:

```
add_record = "INSERT INTO fruit (name, variety) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (new_fruit, new_fruit_type)
```

Imagine the query this would produce:

```
INSERT INTO fruit (name, variety) VALUES (watermelon, something_else)
```

Those values aren't values anymore! They look more like column references (`Unknown column 'watermelon' in 'field list'`)

Instead, you should use prepared statements:

```
query = "INSERT INTO fruit (name, variety) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.execute(query, (new_fruit, new_fruit_type))
```

This will automatically take care of the parameterization for you, and will prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)